# How to make mxCompactTreeLayout right to left? invert not working

Tags: mxgraph

Update #1:

Here are some new clues, looks `invert` just exchanges `source` and `target` of the edge, but does not change the direction of the tree.

The effect of swapping root and v1 is the same as set `invert` to `true`

```js
const root = graph.insertVertex(parent, 'root', 'Root', 0, 0, 60, 40);

const v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, 'child-2', 'Child 1', 0, 0, 60, 40);

graph.insertEdge(parent, null, null, root, v1);

const v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, 'child-1', 'Child 2', 0, 0, 60, 40);

graph.insertEdge(parent, null, null, root, v2);
```

the new demo: https://codepen.io/hungtcs/pen/eYpRGNg

Is there a way to change the direction(right-to-left) of the tree?

---

Origin:

I want to create a right-to-left compact tree layout, finally I found `inverted` variable of `mxCompactTreeLayout`, but it doesn't work, my [live demo](https://codepen.io/hungtcs/pen/oNjwZvz)

> [mxCompactTreeLayout.invert](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/layout/mxCompactTreeLayout-js.html#mxCompactTreeLayout.invert) Specifies if edge directions should be inverted

This is the case where inverted is false

[image]

This is the case when inverted is true, the layout is broken

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer but more a clue... If in the getLayout function you put a console.log("id:", cell.id) in your getLayout function I get over 100 prints, only a few of them being wrapper-1 or wrapper-2, most of them being numbers... I'm wondering whether the invert is really applied to all the elements or not, also depending on the drawing order... Let me know if this helps...

Comment: Thank you @Marco,  I made some new discoveries because of your prompt

Comment: I'm glad if this helped somehow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible out of the box, but if you change a bit of internals of `mxCompactTreeLayout`, it may work:

There is this [attachParent](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph2/blob/3e560dbfa0377b72236dec4ed53d65d22f9a65cf/javascript/src/js/layout/mxCompactTreeLayout.js#L681) function:

```js
mxCompactTreeLayout.prototype.attachParent = function(node, height)
{
    var x = this.nodeDistance + this.levelDistance;
    var y2 = (height - node.width) / 2 - this.nodeDistance;
    var y1 = y2 + node.width + 2 * this.nodeDistance - height;

    node.child.offsetX = x + node.height;
    node.child.offsetY = y1;

    node.contour.upperHead = this.createLine(node.height, 0,
        this.createLine(x, y1, node.contour.upperHead));
    node.contour.lowerHead = this.createLine(node.height, 0,
        this.createLine(x, y2, node.contour.lowerHead));
};
```

Don't know why offsetX depends on height, but if you change that one assignment to `-(x + node.height)` your example will look like that:

[image: reversedLayout]

just add this:

```js
layout.attachParent = function(node, height)
{
    var x = this.nodeDistance + this.levelDistance;
    var y2 = (height - node.width) / 2 - this.nodeDistance;
    var y1 = y2 + node.width + 2 * this.nodeDistance - height;

    node.child.offsetX = -(x + node.height);
    node.child.offsetY = y1;

    node.contour.upperHead = this.createLine(node.height, 0,
        this.createLine(x, y1, node.contour.upperHead));
    node.contour.lowerHead = this.createLine(node.height, 0,
        this.createLine(x, y2, node.contour.lowerHead));
};
```

or check example https://codepen.io/godric3/pen/rNOwRxK